# change gps location android with adb

Tags: android, testing, gps, location, adb

i have a problem trying to use adb on android device

```
adb devices List of devices attache 42002d1c4e9934d3 device

adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps


 adb shell am startservice -a 
 com.android.location.fused.FusedLocationProviderService --ef latitude 40.7128 --ef longitude -74.0060 --ef accuracy 10
```

and returns me

```
 adb shell am startservice -a com.android.location.fused.FusedLocationProviderService --ef latitude 40.7128 --ef longitude -74.0060 --ef accuracy 10
```

I need to change the gps location of the mobile for tests